# grunt error in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am using windows machine, when i try to run the grunt comment getting error.

> ```
> Warning:
> You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
> More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
>  Use --force to continue.
> Aborted due to warnings.
> ```

I found the solution in internet need to install **gem install sass**

I tried to install - **gem install sass** - getting error.

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0) in any repository

I found the solution in online **gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/**

I tried to install - **gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/**

> Error fetching https://rubygems.org/:
>           Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively re fused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port
>   443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Any suggestions to fix this errors.

Comment: you should add what version of rubygems your using

Comment: This is a temporary out of service problem. Rubygems is known to be occasionally down on `443` port. Use `http://rubygems.org/` for now.